# android listener for when an ImageView gets an image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I am asynchronously loading an image into an ImageView. I would like to be notified of when the image has been loaded. Is there a listener of sort that I can attach to my ImageView that will tell me when the image has been loaded? For some background: I am using BitmapFun, which is similar to Picasso, for loading an image into an ImageView and those libraries work asynchronously. And I need to know, programmatically of course, when the image has been loaded.

I don't mind creating a custom ImageView by extending ImageView and then somewhere in my CustomImageView define a callback function for knowing when the image has been loaded into the ImageView.

Comment: I think you answered your own question. Extending the `ImageView` and adding some callback functionality on setting new image should not be a big deal. BitmapFun will most like utilize `setImageBitmap` or `setImageDrawable`.

Comment: I think it is better to set a listener for your loader instead of imageView